# SonarQube analysis works in IDE but not in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

Which versions am I using (SonarQube, Scanner, Plugin, and any relevant extension):

- SonarQube 7.9.1 (on a remote server)
- Sonar maven plugin 3.7.0.1746 (in my pom.xml file)
- Jenkins 2.222.1 (local server)
- Maven 3.6.0

#### What am I trying to achieve:

I want to perform an analysis with a Jenkins Pipeline with my remote server

#### What have I tried so far to achieve this :

I have succeed to do an analysis with my IDE (intelliJ) and it works with the command :

```
mvn -B sonar:sonar
```

After that, the server note the last analysis with the Quality Gate.
Nevertheless, it does not work with my Jenkins Pipeline.

I do not understand why it works with the IDE and not with Jenkins.

I have put in my pom.xml a `sonar.login` which is a specific user token. This user has the right to execute an analysis on this particular project. In my `~/.m2/settings.xml`, I have put the `sonar.host.url`.

I also tried to set up manually a SonarQube server in Jenkins (in system configuration). I put there the url and my token thanks to a secret text but it does not work to.

I have also generated a Webhook but this is for the qualitygate variable in the pipeline and I don’t think it matters here.

I don’t know what to test now…
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: hi, as you seem quiet new to stackoverlfow, here some recommendations: please add logout put regarding the sonar step of your pipeline. If there is not enough information please increase the output level. like in gradle with the flag `--info`. it helps us to help you. we cant tell right now, if there is a connection issue or maybe some misconfiguration. thank you

Comment: Can you share the screenshot logs of jenkins and  pom.xml maybe then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok now : I have added on a sonar installer in the settings. In addition I move the `sonar.host.url` from `~/.m2/settings.xml` to my `pom.xml` file.